# Timer doesn't start running

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to make a normal Timer in Javascript and started coding something with help of some Tutorials.

I did it the same way as in the tutorial but my timer actually doesn't start running, and i don't know why.

Here is my Code:

```
var time = 0;
        var running = 0;

        function startPause() {
            if(running == 0){
                running = 1;
                increment();
            }
            else{
                running = 0;
            }
        }

        function reset(){
            running = 0;
            time = 0;
            document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Start";

        }
        function increment() {
                if(running == 1){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    time++;
                    var mins = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60);
                    var secs = Math.floor(time / 10);
                    var tenths = time % 10;
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs + ":" + tenths;

                           }, 100);
                }
        }
</script>
```

i also made a fiddle you can check out here: https://jsfiddle.net/adamswebspace/5p1qgsz9/

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: you have got 3 functions, but nowhere in your sample do you actually call any of them. You haven't included in your sample here all the code which is in the fiddle, which is confusing to the reader. In your fiddle, there's a JS error "startPause is not a function", which is simply because you need to include the function before the code that calls it. In JSFiddle terms, just change the Javascript options so that the loadType is "nowrap - in head". https://jsfiddle.net/5p1qgsz9/1/ The other problem is that the timer only runs once - I think you need setInterval instead of setTimeout.

Comment: I think what you need is setInterval rather that setTimeout. setTimeout will execute it only once.

Comment: Okay i try that out in my fiddle and try setTimeout for my timer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared a bit your code, and used setInterval instead of setTimeOut;
note that you have to use clearInterval in order to stop the timer

```
var time = 0;
var running = 0;
var timer = null;
function increment() {
    time++;
    var mins = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60);
    var secs = Math.floor(time / 10);
    var tenths = time % 10;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs + ":" + tenths;
}
function startPause() {
    if (running === 0) {
        running = 1;
        timer = setInterval(increment, 1000);
    } else {
        running = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

function reset() {
    running = 0;
    time = 0;
    document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Start";

}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot to understand my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind the function like the following

```
var vm = this;

vm.startPause = function startPause() {
  if (running == 0) {
    running = 1;
    vm.increment();
  } else {
    running = 0;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7hmbox7/

Answer (score 0):

In order for `onclick` to find the function in your code. It must be supplied in a `<script>` tag for JSFiddle.

You can just add

```
<script>

/** JS Here */

</script>
```

and it will work.

Keep in mind that all the errors coming from JS are showed in the console of your browser inspector.

https://jsfiddle.net/dzskncpw/